# Posting Model WEB API NET CORE 6

Tags: database, api, asp.net-core-webapi, form-post

```
public partial class Thongtin
{
    public string? Id { get; set; }

    public string? Hovaten { get; set; }

    public string? Sodienthoai { get; set; }

    public string? Diachilapdat { get; set; }

    public string? Tenhinhanh { get; set; }

    public string? Hinhanh { get; set; }
}
```

```
 public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile file, Thongtin a )
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                var uniqueFileName = GetUniqueFileName(file.FileName);


                var uploads = Path.Combine(Environment.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
                var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, uniqueFileName);
                file.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
            }
        


            return Ok("upload successfull");
        }
```

This is my reseult when i put object and type IFORMFile
[image]

The result not have object
[image]

```
 public IActionResult Upload(  IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                var uniqueFileName = GetUniqueFileName(file.FileName);


                var uploads = Path.Combine(Environment.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
                var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, uniqueFileName);
                file.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
            }
        


            return Ok("upload successfull");
        }
```

Because i want to save text and image name to database and file image to forder source code

I want to get form upload and object same time in method post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the Thongtin class with the IFormFile type. Then using 1 parametr for the API with  `[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]` and `[FromForm]` attribute.

```
public class Thongtin
    {      
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public IFormFile? file { get; set; }
        public string? Hovaten { get; set; }
        public string? Sodienthoai { get; set; }
        public string? Diachilapdat { get; set; }
        public string? Tenhinhanh { get; set; }
        public string? Hinhanh { get; set; }
    }
```

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        public IActionResult Upload([FromForm] Thongtin a)
        {
            if (a.file != null)
            {
                var uniqueFileName = GetUniqueFileName(a.file.FileName);
                var uploads = Path.Combine(Environment.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
                var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, uniqueFileName);
                a.file.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
            }
            return Ok("upload successfull");
        }
```

Then you can post file and parameters at the same time
[image]
[image]

Comment: but i dont know how to mapping IFormFile to sql server model